# what does background: transparent url(); do?

Tags: css, background

I saw a css code where it was like

```
   body { background: transparent url ('background.jpg') repeat scroll;}
```

What does the transparent value do? I tried google'ing about this, but no help. Wouldn't background.jpg just override it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`transparent` is the color. An element can have both a background image and a background color.

The above is equivalent to:

```
body {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('background.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

The color is important in general if e.g. the background image fails to load, or the image contains transparent regions, or the image does not repeat to fill the entire area (which is admittedly not the case in your example).

However, since `transparent` is the "initial value", it is never necessary when using the `background` shorthand, since the shorthand automatically sets all unspecified properties to their initial value.

Thus, the only use case where `transparent` makes sense as a background color involves:

1. not using the shorthand, but instead directly using the `background-color` property;
2. using it to override another selector applying directly to that element.

An example would be

```
body.foo { background-color: blue; }
body.foo.bar { background-color: transparent; }
```

Comment: I'm afraid that is not correct. Explicitly setting the value makes no difference at all (see my answer).

Comment: Good catch @Pumbaa80, I assumed it was `inherit`. Fixing.

Comment: @MrLister, I said "fixing," not "fixed." *Now* it's fixed ;).

Comment: OK, but your answer still sounds as if you think that `background: url(pic)` can have a different effect than `background: transparent url(pic)`

Comment: @MrLister Ah I see, the shorthand overwrites with the initial value. Will update.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is not required.

> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background
>   Given a valid declaration, the 'background' property first sets all the individual background properties to their initial values, then assigns explicit values given in the declaration.

Since `background-color`'s initial value [is `transparent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-color), it is applied implicitly when setting `background:url(...);`

More precisely, your style rule is equivalent to

```
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url(...);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 0% 0%;
```

in both cases.

However, many authors (including myself) prefer to explicitly set the value

- for readability
- to prevent any browser bugs, or simply
- because they don't know better