# Keep the Div at the Bottom of the Page with an Image in it to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to attempt a DIV that should be placed at the bottom right corner of a page with a close button at the top-right corner in that DIV

I have the following markup with me

```
<div id="message">
    <p>Some Message</p>
    <span class="shut">

    </span>
</div>
```

I have defined the CSS as follows

```
#message{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    height:320px;
    width:310px;
    background: #453fefe;     
    padding: 10px 20px;             
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.shut {
    background: transparent url('shutig.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    right: 4px;
}
```

Unfortunately I don't achieve what I am looking for. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Might find this ALA article worth a read: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the invalid background color, which makes the CSS not work expectedly. Also the close button can't be rendered because you did not set an explicit size for it.

```
#message{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 height:120px;
 width:210px;
 background: #45fefe; /* you set #453fefe which is an invalid color */
 padding: 10px 20px;             
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.shut {
 background: transparent url('http://placehold.it/20x20') 0 0 no-repeat;    
 position: absolute;
 top: 4px;
 right: 4px;
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/rVUEQ/4/)

Comment: Indeed you are the King of CSS. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: my shut button image has a white background. When I place it on the div, the white background shows. How can I prevent that? Shouldn't background: transparent take care of this?

Comment: @user3279259 No - that tells the browser to render a "clear" background for the element; it doesn't modify any media contained within or used as a background. You might want to read up a bit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: ok got my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328204/what-does-background-transparent-url-do but then do I have to make my shut button image trasnparent explicitly?

Comment: @user3279259 of course the `background-color:transparent` is not needed because it's the default. If you need your close button to have some shape, you should use a png or gif image with background transparent. If the shape is just a circle, you can apply the `border-radius:50%` to the `.shut`, otherwise (the shape is complicated) you should use a transparent png or gif image.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute positioning for the .shut it will position it relative to your screen not the parent.
Try playing around with float or use a table

Comment: Actually, absolute positioning works against the closest positioned parent; since the immediate parent is fixed positioned, the absolute positioning is relative to **that** element. You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/KNjK3/